# WTForms equivalent to <input type="time">

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm building a webapp (an educational project for me) with flask that utilizes wtforms and I ran into the following problem:
I need to be able to gather input from the users in the form of start-time and end-time, for which I thought the html5

```
input type="time"
```

would be perfect, however I could not find an equivalent in the wtforms documentation. Googling the problem also did not yield any solutions. The closest thing that seems to be available is the DateTimeLocalField, but I don't want to store/display the date information.
As a workaround I could probably just use 2 SelectFields, one for hours and one for minutes but maybe I'm missing something obvious.
Is there a way to get the DateTime(Local)Field to display only time, or create a 'TimeField' with wtforms?

Comment: They suggest using a dateutil package: http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/ext.html#module-wtforms.ext.dateutil.fields

Comment: Or otherwise, use this plugin: https://wtforms-components.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#timefield

Comment: Thanks man, WTForms-components is exactly what I was looking for!! Can yoy post this as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one?

Comment: It'd be just a link only answer, coming from me. You should answer your own question with an [mcve] included.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Credit to hjpotter92 for the suggestion.

[WTForms-Components](https://wtforms-components.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#timefield) has the exact relevant field available.

```
from wtforms_components import TimeField

class Timeform(FlaskForm):
    start = TimeField('start')
```